# How to create an array of text that includes title and description for images?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I added some pictures in my app that are called from an array. Now I need another array to have text which includes a title and some description for these images.
How can I create this array of text that when an image is clicked, the specific title and description would be shown for that image?

This is the code where pictures are displayed on the Home Screen of the app.

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";

import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";

import Header from '../components/Header';



var loadImageCount = 6;
export default class  PicFlatlist extends Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       loadImageCount: 6,
       images: [
         { url: require("../assets/pic_1.jpg"), id: 1 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_2.jpg"), id: 2 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_3.jpg"), id: 3 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_4.jpg"), id: 4 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_5.jpg"), id: 5 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_6.jpg"), id: 6 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_7.jpg"), id: 7 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_8.jpg"), id: 8 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_9.jpg"), id: 9 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_10.jpg"), id: 10 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_11.jpg"), id: 11 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_12.jpg"), id: 12 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_13.jpg"), id: 13 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_14.jpg"), id: 14 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_15.jpg"), id: 15 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_16.jpg"), id: 16 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_17.jpg"), id: 17 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_18.jpg"), id: 18 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_19.jpg"), id: 19 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_20.jpg"), id: 20 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_21.jpg"), id: 21 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_22.jpg"), id: 22 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_23.jpg"), id: 23 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_24.jpg"), id: 24 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_25.jpg"), id: 25 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_26.jpg"), id: 26 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_27.jpg"), id: 27 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_28.jpg"), id: 28 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_29.jpg"), id: 29 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_30.jpg"), id: 30 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_31.jpg"), id: 31 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_32.jpg"), id: 32 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_33.jpg"), id: 33 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_34.jpg"), id: 34 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_35.jpg"), id: 35 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_36.jpg"), id: 36 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_37.jpg"), id: 37 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_38.jpg"), id: 38 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_39.jpg"), id: 39 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_40.jpg"), id: 40 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_41.jpg"), id: 41 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_42.jpg"), id: 42 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_43.jpg"), id: 43 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_44.jpg"), id: 44 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_45.jpg"), id: 45 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_46.jpg"), id: 46 },
         { url: require("../assets/pic_47.jpg"), id: 47 },
         
       ],
     };
   }

   loadMore = () => {
      var ImageCount = this.state.loadImageCount + 12;
      this.setState({ loadImageCount: ImageCount });
   }

  static navigationOptions = () => {
      return {
        header: (null),
      };
      
    }
  renderFooter = () => {
    if(this.state.loadImageCount < this.state.images.length){
      return (
        <View style={styles.buttonRow}>
          <Icon.Button
            name="sort"
            backgroundColor="#ffa500"
            onPress={() => {this.loadMore()}}
          >
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>View More</Text>
          </Icon.Button>
        </View>
      );
    }
    else{
      return (
        null
      )
    }
  }
  render(){
  return (
    <View >
      <View style={{width:"100%",height:undefined,paddingTop:StatusBar.currentHeight}}>
        <Header />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.outerContainer}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.images.slice(0, this.state.loadImageCount)}
          key={"2"}
          numColumns={2}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.homescreen}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.8}
              onPress={() =>
                this.props.navigation.navigate("Image Details", {
                  SelectedImage: [item],
                })
              }
            >
              <Image
                source={item.url}
                style={{
                  width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.45,
                  height: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.55,
                  borderWidth: 2,
                  borderColor: "white",
                  resizeMode: "cover",
                  marginVertical: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.02,
                  marginHorizontal: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.02,
                }}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );};
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  homescreen: {
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: undefined,
    paddingBottom: Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.1,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  outerContainer: {
    position: "relative",
    marginTop: Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.05,
  },
  buttonRow: {
    margin: 15,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignContent: "center",
    alignSelf: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

This is the code for the page when an image is clicked on:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';

import { NavigationStackProp } from "react-navigation-stack";
import Header from '../components/Header';
import BackHeader from '../components/BackHeader';


var count = 0;
interface Props{
    navigation: NavigationStackProp
}
interface State{
    images: any
}
export default class ImageDetails extends Component<Props,State> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        images: this.props.navigation.getParam("SelectedImage")
    };
  }
  
  render ()  {
    return (
      <View>
      <View style={{width:"100%",height:undefined}}> //,paddingTop:StatusBar.currentHeight
        <BackHeader />
        </View>
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.images}
        numColumns={1}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.homescreen}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={(item) => this.loadImage(item)}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
  loadImage = (item) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.homescreen}>
        <Image
          source={item.item.url}
          style={{
            width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.99,
            height: Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.73,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: "white",
            resizeMode: "cover",
            marginVertical: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.02,
            marginHorizontal: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.02,
          }}
        />
        <Text>Miniature Description</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  homescreen: {
    position: "relative",
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    alignItems: "center",
    alignSelf: 'center',
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Comment: You have provided no code that we can work with. Please provide your code if you want a meaningful answer, or an answer at all.

Comment: @TalmacelMarianSilviu
Thanks for considering and sorry for not posting the code. I thought this could be solved without seeing the code. Now you have all the code.

Answer (score 0):

So I find this answer from Expo Community on Discord. For creating an array, you can either create it inside the main file of your project or a better approach is to create an extra file and add your array file in it and then call it inside the main file. For instance, this is an extra file in my code for creating a array.

```
  image1: {
    title: "Cool Image # 1",
    description: `People setting in a garden`,
  },
  image2: {
    title: "Cool Image # 1",
    description: `People setting in a garden`,
  },
  image3: {
    title: "Cool Image # 1",
    description: `People setting in a garden`,
  },
  image4: {
    title: "Cool Image # 1",
    description: `People setting in a garden`,
  },
  image5: {
    title: "Cool Image # 1",
    description: `People setting in a garden`,
  },
};
```

And this is my main file calling the array.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loadImageCount: 6,
      images: [
        {
          url: require("../assets/pic_1.jpg"),
          id: 1,
          title: ImageData["image1"].title,
          description: ImageData["image1"].description,
        },
        {
          url: require("../assets/pic_2.jpg"),
          id: 2,
          title: "cool image #2",
          description: "Some people sitting in a garden",
        },
```